# I am not able to connect to Redis cloud server through AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, redis, connection

I have written this code as my lambda function so that I can connect to Redis Cloud Server. But when I test the function, it stucks on "Connecting to redis" (console message) and then stops.

Here is the code:

```
const redis = require('redis');
const console = require('console');

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  const redisURL = '***********************************';
  const redisPort = *****;
  const redisPassword = '*****************************';

  const redisRole = 'user'; 

  console.log('Connecting to Redis...');
  const client = redis.createClient({
    host: redisURL,
    port: redisPort,
    password: redisPassword,
    role: redisRole // Add the role name to the connection options
  });

  client.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('Connected to Redis');
    // Perform Redis operations using the 'client' instance

    client.rpush('myList', 'item1', 'item2', 'item3', (err, reply) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error adding item to list:', err);
        callback(err);
      } else {
        console.log('Items added to list:', reply);
        callback(null, 'Success');
      }

      // client.quit();
    });
  });

  client.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error('Error connecting to Redis:', err);
    callback(err);
  });
};
```

All the credentials i.e. host, password and port are correct.

Comment: Where is the Redis server? Is it in an AWS VPC? Is it running on some other cloud service? It's impossible to help you without knowing more details.

Comment: I have made a account on Redis Labs and after taking a subscription, I made a database there.

Comment: Is your Lambda function configured to run in a VPC?

Comment: See [How do I give internet access to a Lambda function that's connected to an Amazon VPC?](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function)

Comment: Yes the VPC has access to internet as it has all the private subnets and NAT gateway.

Comment: The lambda also has access to internet as I tried pinging internet with it and it worked.